# ECMAScript 6 negative binary literal

Tags: javascript, binary, ecmascript-6

With EMCAScript6, I see there's a way to represent [binary literals](http://es6-features.org/#BinaryOctalLiteral) using the `0b` or `0B` prefix. I was experimenting with it, and couldn't find a way to represent a negative number (since it's not using two's-complement). Am I missing something? I can't find where binary literals are explained in the actual spec.

I suppose I could implement it myself with an operation like `~(num - 1)` or `-num`:

```js
function twosComplement(num) {
  return ~(num - 1);
}

var flag = 0b100;

console.log(flag);
console.log(twosComplement(flag));

// is this output normal? I thought binary used a sign bit
console.log(twosComplement(flag).toString(2));
```

Comment: `-0b100`? I don't think binary literals (or any other numeric literals) are supposed to be thought of as tied to a specific binary representation, so you need to indicate a negative literal value if you want a negative result.

Comment: @JeremyBanks You're probably right. I was excited for a moment that maybe they hadn't abstracted that away. Is there a spec reference?

Comment: Numeric literals [are here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals) in the spec, which includes *BinaryIntegerLiteral*, though it doesn't seem to specify the `-` prefix, so I think that's just the negation operator.

Comment: @squint Interesting! I guess I never realized that a negative literal (of any base) is actually interpreted as a positive literal, and *then* it's negated.

Comment: `0b100` is converted to `4` integer on assignment. What's wrong with `-0b100` then? Binary literals are not tied to word size and not real binaries, so isn't `toString()` return value.

Comment: @estus There's nothing "wrong" about it. It's just that the usefulness of binary literals IMO lies in making it easy to visualize the underlying binary when doing bitwise operations. It's just that I can't express the underlying binary of a negative number using this.

Comment: Yeah, that does seem to be the case, at least for the BinaryLiteral. Don't know why they decided that. As far as showing the signed bit, it may have to do with the fact that there's a [single 64 bit numeric type](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-number-type). So if they represented it as `10000100`, that would suggest an 8-but number, and it wouldn't parse back to -4. The finite numbers seem to be in the high 11 bits, so if they did `10000000100`, it still doesn't parse right. I'm just not sure how they'd represent it in that situation.

Comment: ...typed the binary literal [into esprima](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=-0b100%0A), and they do interpret it as the unary negation op.

Answer (score 1):

To input negative number just prefix your literal with `-` sign (unary minus operator):

```
-0b11010 // -26
```

Specification for binary literals is in section [Numeric Literals](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-literals-numeric-literals).

Relevant fragment:

> NumericLiteral :: (...) BinaryIntegerLiteral
>
> BinaryIntegerLiteral :: 0b BinaryDigits

And `BinaryDiggits` are `0` and `1`.